# Error building Qt 5.3.0

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I am trying to compile Qt 5.3.0 to get rid of icu dlls. I have Windows 7 32 bit, MS VS2012. I ran the following command:

```
configure -nomake examples -nomake tests -opengl desktop -prefix C:\\Qt5.3.0_custom -platform win32-msvc2012 -opensource -c++11 -no-icu
```

After a large output I got this error:

```
C:\Qt5.3.0_custom\qtbase\qmake\generators\win32\msvc_nmake.cpp(50) : fatal error
 C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows/registry_p.h': No such file or direct
ory
msvc_vcxproj.cpp
msvc_objectmodel.cpp
C:\Qt5.3.0_custom\qtbase\qmake\generators\win32\msvc_vcproj.cpp(71) : fatal erro
r C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows/registry_p.h': No such file or direc
tory
msbuild_objectmodel.cpp
cesdkhandler.cpp
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BI
N\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
Building qmake failed, return code 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to execute a batch file, so here is the complete process:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat

configure -nomake examples -nomake tests -opengl desktop -prefix C:\\Qt5.3.0_custom -platform win32-msvc2012 -opensource -c++11 -no-icu

nmake
```